# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HttpMethod is required when mocking restTemplate.exhange in JUnit (post call)

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, resttemplate

```
Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(
                anyString(),
                Mockito.eq(HttpMethod.POST),
                Mockito.any(),
                Mockito.eq(String.class)
        )).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK));
```

Mocking the `restTemplate.exchange` (POST method) in JUnit like above. Getting the below error.

What am i doing wrong?
How to get this pass?

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mawzm.png).

Comment: Could you please provide a concrete example? Please, see: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example - Help Center - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try as below.

```
Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(
            ArgumentMatchers.anyString(),
          ArgumentMatchers.any(HttpMethod.class),
          ArgumentMatchers.any(),
          ArgumentMatchers. 
<Class<String>>any())).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>
(HttpStatus.OK));
```